# How did the Nazi toy shop owner (acted by Kenneth Tigar) turn the knife on Jonah Heidelbaum (Logan Lerman)?

Tags: knife-fighting, entertainment

https://youtu.be/cT3QJ_hvIb4?t=317 hails from [Episode 1 of Hunters (2020 TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunters_(2020_TV_series)#Episodes).

How did the old Nazi man get the upper hand over Heidelbaum? I am rattled because whilst holding the knife at the Nazi's throat, Jonah does not appear to have lost his grip or force! Jonah does not appear to be distracted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not in any way reflect reality.  Don't read too much into movie fight scenes.  It's very rare that they actually have realistic martial arts techniques.

There are moves that will reverse a knife back onto the opponent but they don't look like this and are also very hard to pull off.

Movie fights go the way the plot wants them too.  There's not much else to say about it.